# How can I simulate a click on Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I'm struggling to simulate a click on the map. Here is my code.

```
map.fire('click', function ()
    { 
        newDropoff({lng: 27.4199870950609,lat: 53.240419723523775});
        updateDropoffs(dropoffs);
    })
```

The original code is taken from this [guide](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/optimization-api/)

```
map.on('click', function (e) {
    // When the map is clicked, add a new drop off point
    // and update the `dropoffs-symbol` layer
    newDropoff(map.unproject(e.point));
    updateDropoffs(dropoffs);
    });
```

Does anyone know what should be corrected in my code? PS I've checked other sources already

Answer (score 2):

You just pass an object, not a function:

```
map.fire('click', {
  lngLat: new mapboxgl.LngLat(27.42, 53.24)})
})
```

If you need the other properties from [MapMouseEvent](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/events/#mapmouseevent) you will need to add them manually.

Comment: thank you so much. I tried
`map.fire('click', {
 lngLat: new mapboxgl.LngLat(17.42, 43.24)})`
However, here is the error I received.
Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.originalEvent.target')

Comment: Hence my second comment: if you need other properties (eg, `originalEvent`) you will need to add them manually.